# Handling no network situation when posting to FB using FB App installed

Tags: android, facebook, connection

In my app I'm connecting to Facebook and can post image to it. I'm using FB Android API 3.0.

Now, I've found a bug in situation when I run my app, on the phone with FB app installed and authorized, and no Internet connectivity.

When I click Login to FB first time, as the FB app exists and it is authorized, My app figures out that it will communicate with FB through the app, and it is kind a "logged in".

This enables me to share on facebook, and when I click "share" my app sends share to FB app, but as there is no internet connectivity App crashes.

So, what's the proper way to do this.

I plan to implement pre-share check for

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

But I'm not sure this is enough, because If the network is there but very bad, I can get correct information that there is Connectivity, and when the share starts it could again crash the app.

Is there a way to somehow get response from FB App that there is no internet connectivity and handle the message somehow?

Comment: I am sure the FB app checks for network (internet) connectivity similar to how every other app does. The purpose of the FB app with regards to your application is merely to authenticate users with SSO. Once authenticated, your app works with no connection what so ever with the FB app. You can't "tap" into the FB app to check if there is no internet connectivity.

Comment: I understand that, that's why I wrote it is the case with first use only. I've implemented check so if there is no network, I'm not calling FB app either, so I can't get into situation any more.